# Inclusion of missing data with adapted Winsorizing approach for small sample?

Tags: missing-data, small-sample, data-imputation

We have a dataset of patients with a rare condition (n=~10 for each of 2 groups). The participants completed a battery of standardized tests that use a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. In some cases, participants did not pass the 'practice items' so did not start the task, and therefore there was no raw data to convert to a standard score. This resulted in 'missing' data throughout the dataset for different tests. We want to represent the performance of this participants in these cases. I was advised to enter the lowest standard score (e.g., 55) in these cases as a form of single imputation to be able to represent these cases and therefore have a full dataset. My questions are: (1) is this a version of single imputation if the missing data were replaced with a stand-in (such as standard scores of 55)? (2) if this is statistically sound, are there citations or papers you could share so we could refer to them? (3)  if this is statistically sound, would you recommend that we use the same score across standardized tests (e.g., 55), or look up the exact lowest possible standard score for each person based on their age and subtest?

Comment: I'd turn this round: what was the rationale given along with the advice? It doesn't much matter what you call it: it's just guessing. Why not 50? 45? A very small sample size has one consequence: you could explore the consequences of different guesses. With due respect to the rareness of the condition and the likely difficulties of measurement, there is no statistical white magic available that will do anything but fudge the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! The rationale for 55 is that it is the standard score at the <1 percentile  (the lowest end of the normal curve). I did test out analyses with 'imputed scores' and the results are highly comparable, so will stick with non-imputed data. I realize this is less about imputation, and more about how standardized tests are used when participants can't pass the practice items - some testers may advance (unknowingly perhaps) to  item 1, and then the participant would 'earn' the lowest standard score corresponding to a raw score of 0. Then, they are represented (the original goal).

Comment: The normal curve starts at minus infinity in principle. You are referring to some polite convention about reporting very low scores. It's still a kind of guessing. I know this is a very negative comment, but the point remains that if you don't know what values should be you can omit observations or resort to guessing.